# HTA VBScript Checkbox Length by ID

Tags: checkbox, vbscript, hta

I have a series of checkboxes that I am trying to systematically cycle through but I am having a hard time getting the .Length of the checkbox array using GetElementsbyID.

Here's a short example of my HTML (brackets omitted):

```
input type="checkbox" Name="A" ID="A1" Value="Some Value" checked="True"

input type="checkbox" Name="A" ID="A2" Value="Some Value" checked="True"

input type="checkbox" Name="B" ID="B1" Value="Some Value" checked="True"

input type="checkbox" Name="B" ID="B2" Value="Some Value" checked="True"

input type="checkbox" Name="B" ID="B3" Value="Some Value" checked="True"
```

and so on through D4

I have attempted the following:

```
document.getElementByID(chr(65)).Length

document.getElemenstByID(chr(65)).Length

document.getElementByID("A").Length

document.getElementsByID("A").Length
```

I have also tried:

```
somevar = document.getElementByID("A")

arraylength = somevar.Length
```

And:

```
Set someobj = document.getElementByID("A")

For Each Checkbox in someobj

Next
```

In each case I am getting an Object doesn't support this method.  I can get the .Name and .Value using this method, but I cannot get the .Length.  I've even tried to use .Count as a shot in the dark.  As you can see I'm kind of grasping at straws.

Below is the code I am trying to write.  It lives within a function:

```
For AtoD = 65 to 68

  For DoTheThing = 1 to document.getElementByID(chr(AtoD)).Length

   'do some stuff

Next

Next
```

By the way, if I substitute "A" for chr(65) it still fails.  I could write a separate loop for each section A through D but I am trying to use efficient and reusable code.  Is there a way to get the checkbox.Length using the getElementbyID...or really ANY other method?

Thanks in advance.

========================================
Update Below:

Ok, here's the whole script.  Here's the background:  I'm prepping some computers to be deployed into the field that need some errors corrected (because some jackass misconfigured them).  I am going to present a list of options so that the technician can change options situationally.

I have created the checkboxes as you can see.  What I am trying to do is set the InnerHTML of the associated SPAN to the Value of the checkbox.  So, for example, SA1.InnerHTML = A1.Value.  It keeps me from creating an incongruency between what the checkbox is labeled as and what it will actually do.

So, here's the code as it currently sits.  I get object does not support property or method on line 25:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Elections Computer Pre-Deploy Doodad</title> 
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="PreDeploy"
     BORDER="thin"
     SCROLL="auto"
     SCROLLFLAT="no"
     MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
     MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
     NAVIGATABLE="no"
     SELECTION="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     WINDOWSTATE="normal"
     SYSMENU = "yes"
     ICON="res://shell32.dll/2/217"
>

<script language="VBscript"> 
window.resizeTo 1200,800
window.moveTo 10,10

Function DrawScreen
    For AtoD = 65 to 68
        For DoTheThing = 1 to document.getElementByID(chr(AtoD)).Length
            document.getElementByID("S"&chr(AtoD)&DoTheThing).innerText = document.getElementByID(chr(AtoD)&DoTheThing).Value
        Next
    Next    
End Function

</script> 
<body style="font-family:Trebuchet MS; font-size: 18px" onLoad = "DrawScreen()"> 
<table border="1">
<tr><td ID="LEFT" valign="top" style="width:400px">
    <B>Delete Desktop Shortcuts:</B><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="A1" ID="A" Value="SANDBOX webSCORE.website" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SA1"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="A2" ID="A" Value="SANDBOX webSCORE Login.website" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SA2"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="A3" ID="A" Value="webSCORE Login LIVE.website" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SA3"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="A4" ID="A" Value="webSCORE LIVE.website" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SA4"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="A5" ID="A Value="Lenovo Solution Center.lnk" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SA5"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="A6" ID="A" Value="Adobe Reader XI.lnk" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SA6"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="A7" ID="A" Value="DYMO Label v.8.lnk" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SA7"></SPAN><BR>
    <BR>
    <B>Add Desktop Icons</B><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="B1" ID="B" Value="webSCORE Live Link" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SB1"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="B2" ID="B" Value="webSCORE Sandbox Link" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SB2"></SPAN><BR>

</td><td ID="RIGHT" valign="top" style="width:400px"> 
    <B>Printer Nuke Sequence</B><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="C1" ID="C" Value="Copy Dymo Driver to Local PC" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SC1"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="C2" ID="C" Value="Install Dymo Driver" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SC2"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="C3" ID="C" Value="Purge all print jobs" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SC3"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="C4" ID="C" Value="Nuke all print queues" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SC4"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="C4" ID="C" Value="Create local nuke script" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SC5"></SPAN><BR> 
    <BR>
    <B>Misc Stuff:</B><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="D1" ID="D" Value="Disable Notifications" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SD1"></SPAN><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" Name="D2" ID="D" Value="Disable Automatic Updates" checked="True"> <SPAN ID="SD2"></SPAN><BR>
</td></tr>

</table>
<BR>

<BR>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you passing the `Name` attribute value instead of the `ID` attribute value to `GetElementByID()`?

Comment: I've tried it both ways.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

`id` attributes need to be unique (hence the name). Do not create multiple elements with the same ID. If you want to classify elements: use the `class` attribute. Also, the ID of checkbox A5 is missing a closing double quote, and you have 2 elements named `C4`, the latter of which should most likely be named `C5`. Plus, your code for iterating over the `<input>` elements is broken. [`getElementById()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns an [`IHTMLElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa752279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, which doesn't have a `length` property.

Drop either the `name` or the `id` attribute from the `<input>` tags (you don't need both anyway) and make the values of the attribute unique:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="LEFT" valign="top" style="width:400px">
      <b>Delete Desktop Shortcuts:</b><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="A1" value="SANDBOX webSCORE.website" checked="True"> <span id="SA1"></span><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="A2" value="SANDBOX webSCORE Login.website" checked="True"> <span id="SA2"></span><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="A3" value="webSCORE Login LIVE.website" checked="True"> <span id="SA3"></span><br>
      ...
    </td>
    <td id="RIGHT" valign="top" style="width:400px"> 
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then populate the `<span>` attributes with something like this:

```vbs
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^[a-z]\d+$"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each elem In document.getElementsByTagName("input")
  If re.Test(elem.id) Then
    document.getElementById("S" & elem.id).innerText = elem.value
  End If
Next
```

Comment: I've tried various combinations of ID and Name.  There's a lot of things I tried but omitted from my post.  In fact, when I try to run the script using document.getElementByName it is rejected as bad syntax.  I'll try to post some of the actual code in a bit.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: I just updated my original post with the real code I'm using.